# scraping data from wikipedia table

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

I'm just trying to scrape data from a wikipedia table into a panda dataframe.

I need to reproduce the three columns: "Postcode, Borough, Neighbourhood".

```
import requests
website_url = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M').text
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(website_url,'xml')
print(soup.prettify())

My_table = soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable'})
My_table

links = My_table.findAll('a')
links

Neighbourhood = []
for link in links:
    Neighbourhood.append(link.get('title'))

print (Neighbourhood)

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([])
df['PostalCode', 'Borough', 'Neighbourhood'] = pd.Series(Neighbourhood)

df
```

And it returns only the borough...

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may be overthinking the problem, if you only want the script to pull one table from the page. One import, one line, no loops:

```
import pandas as pd
url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M'

df=pd.read_html(url, header=0)[0]

df.head()

    Postcode    Borough         Neighbourhood
0   M1A         Not assigned    Not assigned
1   M2A         Not assigned    Not assigned
2   M3A         North York      Parkwoods
3   M4A         North York      Victoria Village
4   M5A         Downtown Toronto    Harbourfront
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over each row in the table and store the data row by row, not just in one giant list. Try something like this:

```
import pandas
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
website_text = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(website_text,'xml')

table = soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable'})
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

data = []
for row in table_rows:
    data.append([t.text.strip() for t in row.find_all('td')])

df = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=['PostalCode', 'Borough', 'Neighbourhood'])
df = df[~df['PostalCode'].isnull()]  # to filter out bad rows
```

then

```
>>> df.head()

  PostalCode           Borough     Neighbourhood
1        M1A      Not assigned      Not assigned
2        M2A      Not assigned      Not assigned
3        M3A        North York         Parkwoods
4        M4A        North York  Victoria Village
5        M5A  Downtown Toronto      Harbourfront
```

Comment: Great solution using OPs original code +1 from me, but there's a more efficient way using only pandas

Comment: @G.Anderson yup, considered the `read_html` option, but wanted to try to help OP understand why their original code wasn't doing what they expected

Answer (score 0):

[Basedig](https://www.basedig.com/) provides a platform to download Wikipedia tables as Excel, CSV or JSON files directly. Here is a link to the Wikipedia source: https://www.basedig.com/wikipedia/

If you do not find the dataset you are looking for on Basedig, send them the link to your article and they'll parse it for you.
Hope this helps