# Wikitables to CSV

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I feel like i'm close to getting there. But can't think of a way to make this lists into a .csv. Could anybody help?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

wiki = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mass_shootings_in_the_United_States')

soup = BeautifulSoup(wiki.content, 'html.parser')

tables = soup.find_all('table', class_='wikitable sortable')

column_names = [item.get_text() for item in tables[0].find_all('th')]

content = [item.get_text() for item in tables[0].find_all('td')]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)
```

Comment: do you want the table convert it into csv???

Comment: Yes! I know how to do a df.to_csv(), but I can't get the DataFrame right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scraping data from wikipedia table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54890708/scraping-data-from-wikipedia-table)

Comment: Use pd.read_html like below

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

wiki = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mass_shootings_in_the_United_States')

soup = BeautifulSoup(wiki.content, 'html.parser')
tables = soup.find_all('table', class_='wikitable sortable')
#column_names = [item.get_text() for item in tables[0].find_all('th')]
alltables=pd.DataFrame()
for x in tables:
  df = pd.read_html(str(x))
  alltables=alltables.append(df,ignore_index=True)
print(alltables)
#appended_data = pd.concat(appended_data)  
alltables.to_csv('test.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks, Giovani!! This worked for the first one, I'll make it get all of them now.

Comment: You can also just call `pd.read_html()` on the URL itself and it will create a list of dataframes of _all_ the tables on the page that can be indexed to get the table needed (`[0]` for 2019, `[1]` for 2018...). No need for BS4 or requests

Comment: @luka1156 I added with all tables