# How can I append these two beautiful soup objects into a dataframe simultaneously?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to add the date and dividends off yahoo finance at the same time into a dataframe. This way the dates match together. Not really sure how to do this because I don't know how to use both for loops at the same time. Hoping you might be able to make an attempt. Thank you!

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
import sys
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/history?period1=1570838400&period2=1602460800&interval=div%7Csplit&filter=div&frequency=1d&includeAdjustedClose=true"

HEADERS = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"
}

page = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

dividend = soup.findAll("strong")
date = soup.find_all('td', class_='Py(10px) Ta(start) Pend(10px)')


dividends = []
for f in dividend:
    dividends.append(f.text)

dates = []
for f in date:
    dates.append(f.text)

print(dates, dividends)
```

Comment: What is your current output, and what is your expected output? Also, if you want dataframes, why not use pandas read_html instead of bs4?

Comment: Current output is a list of the dates and a list of the dividends. I'd like the output to be a dataframe with a date column and a dividend column. Not really sure how to use read_html tbh!

Comment: You can `zip` your lists together and make a dataframe out of the result, or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54890708/scraping-data-from-wikipedia-table/54891072#54891072) shows how to use pandas to read tables directly from a static webpage

Comment: For example, given your `url` variable, calling `pd.read_html(url)[0]` gives you a nice neat dataframe that you can manipulate all you want (it has too many columns but that's easy to trim)

Comment: Actually that worked really well. But when I try to pass that function for 500 different stocks I get ```urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable```

Comment: It depends how you're doing it, but if I had to guess, your connection is being rate limited for sending 500 requests too fast