# How to print this list into DataFrame -Python/BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

The output for this code prints each row on the website provided below.

However it also includes the tags. Essentially I would like to print all rows into a dataFrame, which i can put on Excel.

.text would not work because i am using find_all as there are tags that repeat in name.

How would the process be to remove the unwanted tags, and then have the list into a DF, replicating the website?

Thanks.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
productlinks=[]
r=requests.get(url)
soup= BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
content=soup.find_all('tr')
for item in content:
    title=item.find_all('td')
    print(title)
```

Comment: What about `pd.read_html()` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54890708/scraping-data-from-wikipedia-table/54891072#54891072)?

Comment: i get this error- raise ImportError("lxml not found, please install it")
ImportError: lxml not found, please install it

Comment: thank you, this works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to use `pandas.read_html`:

```
import pandas as pd

url='https://sitc.sitcancer.org/2020/abstracts/titles/'
df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
print(df)
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

Prints:

```
       #  ...                                           Keywords
0      1  ...  Adoptive immunotherapy; Monocyte/Macrophage; T...
1      2  ...  CAR T cells; Immune monitoring; Inflammation; ...
2      3  ...  Antibody; Biomarkers; Immune monitoring; T cel...
3      4  ...  Biomarkers; RNA; Solid tumors; Tumor microenvi...
4      5  ...  Antibody; B cell; Biomarkers; Immune monitorin...
..   ...  ...                                                ...
730  752  ...  Gene expression; Neoantigens; Regulatory T cel...
731  753  ...  Gene expression; Neoantigens; Regulatory T cel...
732  754  ...  Biomarkers; Chemokine; Chemotherapy; Costimula...
733  755  ...  Chemokine; Granulocyte; Myeloid cells; MDSC; T...
734  756  ...  Gene expression; Immune contexture; Immune sup...

[735 rows x 6 columns]
```

And saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: i get this error- raise ImportError("lxml not found, please install it")
ImportError: lxml not found, please install it

Comment: @VoidS Try to install `lxml` package. with `python3 -m pip install lxml` or similar command.

Comment: Thank you, and finally can you please explain the *[0*] after (url) in line 3

Comment: @VoidS `pd.read_html()` return list of all tables, but in this case we want first (and only one), so `[0]`